# Injective? Surjective? Bijective? None?

Tags: functions

Is the following diagram representative of an injective, surjective, or bijective function? (or none)

[image: pic]

The reason why I'm asking is because by the definitions of injectivity and surjectivity, this seems to be bijective.

> We can see that if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$, so $f$ is injective. Likewise, every element in the image has at least one corresponding element in the domain, so it is surjective. Therefore, it is bijective.

Of course, this seems extremely fishy. Have I misunderstood something or messed up somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a function, because by definition of a function: an x value is mapped to at most one y value. The x value in your diagram is mapped to two y values, hence making f not a function.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a function, because every function has to associate exactly one element of codomain (right set) to any element of domain (left set). This example doesn't satisfy the requirement, so it cannot be a function.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a function....$~~~~~$

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram represents a "function" that is not well-defined, i.e. for a fixed $x$ it is not clear what the value of $f(x)$ is. In other words: This is crap.

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I didn't even consider that. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a function because the element in the domain is mapped to precisely two elements. To a function is injective, surjective, or even bijective, it must be a function. However, every function need not be injective nor surjective (hence, not even bijective).